# Moving object at the same time

Tags: jquery

```
div {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
<div class="first" style="background:#DC143C;">
</div>
<br>
<div class="second" style="background:#CD5C5C;">
</div>
<br>
<div class="third" style="background:#FF69B4;">
</div>
<br>
<div class="fourth" style="background:#FF7F50;">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("class").click(function(){
            $(".first").animate({
                left: '250px'
            });
        });

    $(".third").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate().css({
            backgroundColor: '#FFF552'
        });
    })

    $(".first").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: 300
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

I finished this application and make it works without the button. But now I need to make this four object moving at the same time. I have no idea how to make it.

Comment: You can put a click event on anything. What's wrong with a button, though?

Comment: Do you mean launch the animation without click ?

Comment: `"How can I make this application without button?"` - Replace the `<button>` element with something else?  What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to animate the div, I will leave that exercise to you. In this case all you have to do is wire up the event properly and there are many ways to do so. Please look at following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhstoh8s/). This **may not** fit to your need entirely but it may give you some idea.

Also look at following methods and see how it works in detail.

```
setInterval
setTimeout
```

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: If this was helpful would you please mark this as answer. It's up to you though.